# Java in Clojure, Evaluation question

Tags: clojure

Is there a detailed explanation for results obtained on evaluating the following on REPL.

```
(.PI Math)
```

gives

```
IllegalArgument Exception
```

while

```
(. Math PI)
```

evaluates to

```
3.141592653589793
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The explanation is at [http://clojure.org/java_interop](http://clojure.org/java_interop#dot).

```
user> (macroexpand '(.PI Math))
(. (clojure.core/identity Math) PI)
```

`(identity Math)` returns the `Class` object representing the `Math` class.  You're trying to access an instance member called `PI` in this `Class` object, but it doesn't exist.  (This is different from accessing a static member called `PI` in the `Math` class.)  You would only ever use this `Class` object for reflection, or to pass a Class around to other methods as an Object, or those sorts of things.

```
user> (class (identity Math))
java.lang.Class
user> (.getName (identity Math))
"java.lang.Math"
user> (.getName Math)
"java.lang.Math"
user> (.getMethods Math)
#<Method[] [Ljava.lang.reflect.Method;@12344e8>
user> (vec (.getMethods Math))
[#<Method public static int java.lang.Math.abs(int)> #<Method public static long java.lang.Math.abs(long)> #<Method public static float java.lang.Math.abs(float)> ...]
user> (.getField Math "PI")
#<Field public static final double java.lang.Math.PI>
user> (.getDouble (.getField Math "PI") Math)
3.141592653589793
```

The shortest way to do what you want is probably `Math/PI`.

```
user> (macroexpand '(Math/PI))
(. Math PI)
user> Math/PI
3.141592653589793
user> (. Math PI)
3.141592653589793
```